# Can I get a stat test and a Beginner's Luck test from the same skill in an extended conflict?

Tags: burning-wheel

Burning Wheel Gold states that only the highest test in an extended conflict counts. For example, if I roll Axe four times in fight, getting two Routines, a Difficult, and a Challenging test, I'd just record the Challenging test (unless I needed just one more test to raise my skill, in which case I could count one of the other ones).

How does this work with Beginner's Luck tests in extended conflicts?

Say I enter Duel of Wits with Will 4 and pretty much no social skills. During the conflict, I roll:

- Untrained Persuasion vs. Ob 2 (Ob 1 doubled) — potentially worth a Routine test to learn Persuasion
- Untrained Persuasion vs. Ob 8 (Ob 4 doubled) — potentially worth a Difficult Will test
- Untrained Seduction vs. Ob 2 (Ob 1 doubled) — potentially worth a Routine test to learn Seduction
- Untrained Seduction vs. Ob 2 (Ob 1 doubled) — potentially worth a(nother) Routine test to learn Seduction

At the end of the Duel of Wits, which tests should I actually record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginner's Luck tests are distinct from stat tests. [Only count one of each](http://www.burningwheel.org/forum/showthread.php?8039-Fight-and-Other-questions) in a Series of Rolls (BWG 45).

> - Untrained Persuasion vs. Ob 2 (Ob 1 doubled)

A test to learn Persuasion.

> - Untrained Persuasion vs. Ob 8 (Ob 4 doubled)

A Difficult Will test, unless you get a Challenging one in this series.

> - Untrained Seduction vs. Ob 2 (Ob 1 doubled)

A test to learn Seduction.

> - Untrained Seduction vs. Ob 2 (Ob 1 doubled)

A would-be test to learn Seduction, except that you've already logged one this series, so it doesn't count for anything.